# How to make the order in which data is input into StringIO irrelevant? - Python

Tags: python, pygtk

I've written a very simple app that based on user input generates a configuration file. However the order in which the data is dumped from StringIO into the actual conf file matters for the program using the file. The way I've addressed this in my code was a top to bottom data input model. But if the user enters data out of order, this will cause the program to fail or the resulting conf file will become useless. Is there a way of re-conciliating random data input order and making sure that the data from StringIO is inserted in a specific order?

Currently the code looks like this (and it got to this stage with a lot of help from you guys!)

```
        self.output = StringIO.StringIO()     

    context = self.toolbar.get_style_context()
    context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)



def on_servername_activate(self, widget):
    output = StringIO.StringIO()         
    servername = widget.get_text()
    self.output.write("USHARE_NAME="+servername+'\n')

def on_netif_changed(self, widget):
    netif = widget.get_active_text()
    self.output.write("USHARE_IFACE="+netif+'\n')

def on_port_activate(self, widget):
    port = widget.get_text()
    self.output.write("USHARE_PORT="+port+'\n')

def on_telprt_activate(self, widget):
    telprt = widget.get_text()
    self.output.write("USHARE_TELNET_PORT="+telprt+'\n')

def on_dirs_activate(self, widget):
    dirs = widget.get_text()
    self.output.write("USHARE_DIR="+dirs+'\n')

def on_iconv_toggled(self, widget):
    iconv = widget.get_active()
    if iconv == True:
        self.output.write("USHARE_OVERRIDE_ICONV_ERR="+"True"+'\n')
    else:
        self.output.write("USHARE_OVERRIDE_ICONV_ERR="+"False"+'\n')

def on_webif_toggled(self, widget):
    webif = widget.get_active()
    if webif == True:
       self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_WEB="+"yes"+'\n')
    else:
       self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_WEB="+"no"+'\n')

def on_telif_toggled(self, widget):
    telif = widget.get_active()
    if telif == True:
        self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_TELNET="+"yes"+'\n')
    else:
        self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_TELNET="+"no"+'\n')

def on_xbox_toggled(self, widget):
    xbox = widget.get_active()
    if xbox == True:
        self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX="+"yes"+'\n')
    else:
        self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX="+"no"+'\n')

def on_dlna_toggled(self, widget):
    dlna = widget.get_active()
    if dlna == True:
        self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA="+"yes"+'\n')
    else:
        self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA="+"no"+'\n')

def on_commit_clicked(self, widget):
    commit = self.output.getvalue()
    logfile = open('/home/boywithaxe/Desktop/ushare.conf','w')
    logfile.write(commit)

def on_endprogram_clicked(self, widget):
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Why can't the code that reads it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the code so that instead of writing the config file string whenever a field is changed, you're changing the value of a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in memory. Then, have your on_commit_clicked function use that dictionary to build the config file string exactly as you need it.

Comment: I think that's what I'll do, thanks for your suggestion confirming my original idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate data collection from output generation. Imagine something like a separate `ConfigBuilder` class with, say, `telnet_port`, `ushare_iface`, `ushare_dir` attributes and a `build()` method which just returns a generated string blob. Then your methods will just set the fields of the `builder`:

```
def on_servername_activate(self, widget):
    servername = widget.get_text()
    self.builder.ushare_name = servername
```

and when user clicks on the Commit button, you generate the config and write it to a file:

```
def on_commit_clicked(self, widget):
    logfile = open('/home/boywithaxe/Desktop/ushare.conf','w')
    logfile.write(self.builder.build())
```

If you don't want to have a separate Builder class, you can get away with just collecting input data in a dictionary or even your window class's member fields:

```
class MyApp(...):

    ushare_name = None
    ... more fields to store user input

    def can_build(self):
        if self.ushare_name and
           self.ushare_xxx and
           self.ushare_yyy and
           self.phase_of_moon_is_right():
            return True
        return False

    def build_config(self):
        return "BLAH =" + self.ushare_name + ...

    def on_servername_activate(self, widget):
        servername = widget.get_text()
        self.ushare_name = servername

    def on_commit_clicked(self, widget):
        if self.can_build():
            logfile = open('/home/boywithaxe/Desktop/ushare.conf','w')
            logfile.write(self.build_config())
        else:
            display_some_warning_message("Data incomplete, the commit button should've been hidden/disabled so the user can't click until the app has all data it needs")
```

Comment: I think The dictionary idea is better. I have considered it at early stages but then just ignored that idea. I'll get onto that first thing tomorrow and let you know the results.

Comment: Well, I think a separate `ConfigBuilder` would be a cleaner solution from the point of separating UI from logic, but that's an (almost) purely aesthetic difference. A dict would do just fine too.

Comment: I experimented a bit and created a `ConfigBuilder` as well as a dictionary, in two different versions of the code, but at runtime, I get a TypeError. Specifically  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`.I checked and the data assigned to `self.ushare_xxxxxx` is indeed an `str`. I'm asking out of curiosity, but why is the type misread?

Comment: If the exception says `NoneType` - I'm pretty sure somewhere you'

Comment: ...trying to concatenate None and a string. Your application need to check if it has all the data it needs before trying to build the config - I've edited my answer to show how it can be done. The UI should somehow reflect this too - i.e. the "commit" button should only appear when all the data is entered. Using some sensible defaults may help too, so user don't have to enter a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate each function that needs it (a simple method that takes widget and returns a suitable - or or potentially a class decorator that blitz's the 'on_*' methods)- you have a lot of repetition and have the decorator append to a list or something.

```
def on_webif_toggled(self, widget):
    webif = widget.get_active()
    if webif == True:
       self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_WEB="+"yes"+'\n')
    else:
       self.output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_WEB="+"no"+'\n')
```

I should note that `== True` should be correctly written as `is True` or just `if webif:`.An identity check is more efficient than an equality check.

Comment: Thanks for this remark, it also makes the code easier to read.